# Adding a "REMOVE" link beside a textbox result by an array

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

[+] //each time I click this button the textbox will generate and I want to have a link beside each textbox, link is "remove" when I click "REMOVE" the textbox will remove..

[hello1]     Remove

[hello2]     Remove

[hello3]     Remove

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var i=0,j=0;
var t1= new Array(); 
function createtext(){
  i++;
  t1[i]=document.createElement('input');
  t1[i].type='text';
  t1[i].name='text'+i;
  t1[i].value = "hello"+i;
  t1[i].size = 10;
  document.forms[0].appendChild(t1[i]);
  var mybr=document.createElement("br");
  document.forms[0].appendChild(mybr);
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY >
  <form action="" method="get" name="f1">

    <input name="b1" type="button" onClick="createtext()" value="+">

    <input name="b1" type="Submit"><br>

  </form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/YuXP8/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a remove button along with the input tag like this:

```
var i=0,j=0;
var t1= [];

function add(){
    i++;
    var parent = document.forms[0];
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type='text';
    input.name='text'+i;
    input.value = "hello"+i;
    input.size = 10;
    t1.push(input);
    div.appendChild(input);
    var removeButton = document.createElement("button");
    removeButton.innerHTML = "Remove";
    removeButton.onclick = function(e) {
        this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
        return(false);
    };
    div.appendChild(removeButton);
    parent.appendChild(div);
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ky9nv/

This code makes it easier to remove an input element and it's associated button by enclosing them in a containing div.  A clicked button can then just get it's parent container and remove that.

And, since your question is tagged with jQuery (thought it doesn't save you a lot here), here's a version that uses jQuery:

```
var i=0,j=0;
var t1= [];

function add(){
    i++;
    var div = $('<div>');
    var input = $('<input>')
        .attr({
            size: '10',
            type: 'text',
            name: 'text' + i,
            value: 'hello' + i
        }).appendTo(div).get(0);
    t1.push(input);
    $('<button>Remove</button>')
        .click(function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        }).appendTo(div);
    $("#myForm").append(div);
}

add();
add();

$("#add").click(add);
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/nbXak/

Comment: thank u so much jfriend00.. i dont have formal training in java hahah so i did not know whats an element.. and other terminologies in jvascript by the way thank you so much. ill study more so some day i will help yah..

Comment: @RobertJohnConcepcion - I added a version that uses jQuery so you can see how that works (though it doesn't save you a lot in this instance).

Comment: do u have some reference website for java review? hahah XD couz i dont know the some words like child,appendTo,parent sorry im a slow person T_T hahah

Comment: @RobertJohnConcepcion - A very good reference on javascript DOM methods: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM.  The jQuery reference: http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page.  Other than that, there are hundreds of thousands of web pages that help so you can always google anything in this area and find answers.

Comment: do u know how can i get the last value of i? and echo it to php?

Comment: @RobertJohnConcepcion - I'm not sure what you mean.  Within your page, the last value of `i` used is in the `i` global variable.  To get it to your PHP server, you'd have to send it to the server in some way (ajax call, form submit, get request, etc...).

Comment: i mean is for example i click the add for 5 time so the value of i=5 i want to get the value of i, for example echo"$i";(not working haha xD)

Comment: `i` is in your web page.  It is not on your server.  To get it to your server, you have to send it to your server using one of the methods I listed in my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is simple.

Just add a id attribute with your text field array that will be assigned to each newly created textarea like this:

```
t1[i].id='some_unique_suffix'+i
t1[i].onClick='remove("some_unique_suffix"'+i+')'
```

Then you can go on creating a remove link after each textfield via your loop and pass the id of that particular textfield to a remove function that will be called upon clicking on the remove link like this:

```
function remove(id)
{
    $('#some_unique_suffix'+id).remove(); 
}
```

Hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i=0;
function createtext() {
    i++;
    $('<div id="field'+i+'">​<input type="text" name="text'+i+'" value="Hello'+i+'" size="10" /> <a href="#" onclick="removeField(\'field'+i+'\');">Remove</a></div>').appendTo('#inputsPlaceholder');
}
function removeField (id) {
    $('#'+id).remove();
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="get" name="f1" id="f1">
<input name="b1" type="button" onclick="createtext();" value="+" />
<div id="inputsPlaceholder"></div>
<input name="b1" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/Z3L5C/